# How to trigger input change on click?

Tags: jquery, search, jquery-events, textinput

I have a search filter. The input is shown when the user clicks on the icon-search.

```
<div class="pull-right">
    <a href="" class="search common-sprite icon-search" title="search"></a>
</div>
<div class="input-text-container search" style="display:none;">
    <input type="text" id="textSearch" class="input-text-big search-message" placeholder="Search in your list" />
    <i class="common-sprite cross search"></i>
</div>
```

When the input-text-container is display a cursor line should be displayed before the "Search in your list", and the user should be able immediately start typing in the search term.

I tried the following:

```
 $('.search.icon-search').on(
    'click',
    function() {
    $('#textSearch').trigger('change')
    });
```

but it did not work.

Can anybody help me trigger input change on click?

Answer (score 0):

You want to [`focus`](https://api.jquery.com/focus/) on that element:

```
$('.icon-search').click(function() {
  $('.input-text-container').show().find('input').focus();
});
```